# Verify that the current user is granted access in the appropriate allowedAccounts section of SMSvcHost.exe.config

Tags: wcf

I have getting the above error when i try to start wcf service hosted in windows service. i am using net.tcp binding with port sharing and have updated the SMSSvcHost.exe.config with the correct SID. What else I could be missing which is casuing this error

i noticed on other forums people suggsting rebooting the server and running the service under admin account. don't know how relevant these suggestions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was casued by installtion of .NET Framework 4.0. It upgared net.tcp port sharing as well.

Comment: You can set the "Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service" back to use Framework 3.0/3.5 by modifying the "ImagePath" key of "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetTcpPortSharing" back to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\SMSvcHost.exe". Make sure you stop and start the service of course.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. My solution is grant Administrative right to the application by adding app.manifest file and use this file in the project properties, manifest field. If I am running in Visual Studio, I need to run VS in administrative mode.

That is kind of sucks. I am wondering others have a different solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Running Visual Studio as Administrator worked for me